# php artisan: Call to undefined function App\Http\Services\mcrypt_get_block_size()

Tags: php, homestead, mcrypt, laravel-artisan

I have checked for this solution on other threads but no solution yet. This scenario is different from the ones i saw so hopefully i would get a solution and not marked as a repeat question.

I cloned a laravel5.3 app and ran the necessary migrations and all that good stuff to set it up.
The task is now to run a custom artisan command. Running that i get this mcrypt error

[image]
First thing i did was to install mcrypt extension using brew

```
brew install mcrypt php70-mcrypt
```

Then i added extension=mcrypt.so to my php.ini file

From the command line i typed php --ini and got
[image]
I can see the loaded configuration file. That was where the extension=mcrypt.so was added. I am using homestead so i ran vagrant halt and then vagrant up.

With all these done, i have mcrypt installed with brew, the extension added to php.ini file and restarted vagrant - all these i saw on other threads but none of these worked for me.

Any ideas how i could make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the code is trying to call the current namespace's `mcrypt_get_block_size`, you probably meant the global namespace's `mcrypt_get_block_size` , which you can access by prepending \  to it, so it looks like `\mcrypt_get_block_size(?)`

this question gotta be a duplicate though, probably